# Access private IP of different security group inside the Openshift cluster

Tags: kubernetes, networking, redis, openshift

Currently, Openshift 4 is deployed in AWS, and my pod is deployed in one of the worker nodes and this is one security group.

Redis cluster is installed in another security group, and I need to access this cluster private IP's inside my container

Please share any references, how we can achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

openshift cluster and redis cluster were in different VPC, VPC peering was required to communicate with the private IP and we need to update the route tables.